# Using colors with Hex values in my UWP app

Tags: uwp

I want to give users the possibility to set colors like it's done in Blend or Photoshop using HEX-values. How can I store that and use in my XAML UI?

Comment: What do you want to do exactly? User will write HEX value (#FFFFFF) to TextBox and you want to change color of something to that color?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably the easiest way to use the standard `Windows.UI.Color` class to select colors. But to convert it to a HEX value, it's a simple as this:

```
Windows.UI.Color c = Windows.UI.Colors.Red;
string hexString = string.Format("#{0:X2}{1:X2}{2:X2}", c.R, c.G, c.B);
```

To use a HEX value in your XAML, you have to use a Converter. For instance:

```
public class HexColorConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        if (!(value is Windows.UI.Color)) return null;

        Windows.UI.Color c = (Windows.UI.Color)value;
        string hex = string.Format("#{0:X2}{1:X2}{2:X2}", c.R, c.G, c.B);
        return hex;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        if (!(value is string)) return null;

        Windows.UI.Color c = new Windows.UI.Color();
        string t = (string)value;

        try
        {
            c.A = (byte)255;
            c.R = (byte)int.Parse(t.Substring(1, 2), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
            c.G = (byte)int.Parse(t.Substring(3, 2), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
            c.B = (byte)int.Parse(t.Substring(5, 2), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
        }
        catch
        {
            throw (new ArgumentException("Invalid color. Must be something like #AABBCC"));
        }

        return c;
    }
}
```

More on using Converters, [see MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.data.ivalueconverter.aspx)